# Как статически скомпилировать код на C++?

Tags: c++, linux, компиляция, static

Специально возьму простой пример с Hello World:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Моя цель - скомпилировать код СТАТИЧЕСКИ! Т е, чтобы `ldd` был пуст. При обычной сборке я получаю это:

```
 ~ $ ldd a.out
libc++_shared.so
libdl.so
libm.so
libc.so
```

Где достать статические версии данных библиотек (или вообще обойтись без них)?

ОС - Linux!

Comment: Библиотеки стандартной библиотеки C под RedHat находятся в пакете glibc-devel. Вместе с заголовочными файлами, так-что наверное на вашей машине они есть.  Что говорит `gcc a.cpp -static` ?

Comment: Ну совсем пуст этот список быть не может. Все-таки минимальное взаимодействие с системой должно будет остаться.

Comment: может. все вкомпиливается

Comment: Unable to find library: -lc. Не пойму, что за библиотеку ему надо...

Comment: libc оно хочет. Возможно, просто у Вас нет статической версии этой библиотеки

Comment: Просто `gcc your-file.c -static` работает? Если да, то `ldd ./a.out` должен сказать `not a dynamic executable`, а `file ./a.out` упомянуть, что он `statically linked`

Comment: у меня C++ код. А так - спасибо за наводку)